# Row number for query results grouped by a column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has the following columns:
id | fk_id | rcv_date

There may be multiple records with a common fk_id, which represents a foreign key id in a related table.

I need to create a query that will assign a row number to each record, grouped by fk_id, sorted by rcv_date.

I originally began with the following query, which works quite well for sorting and assigning row numbers:

```
SELECT @row:=@row +1 AS ordinality, c.fk_id, rcv_date
FROM (SELECT @row:=0) r, mytable c
ORDER BY rcv_date
```

However -- the row count and sorting is done across the entire dataset. I need the counting to be within a common fk_id. For example, the following sample data would return (the first column represents the row count/ordinality):

```
1 | 5 | 2011-10-01
2 | 5 | 2011-10-14
3 | 5 | 2011-11-02
4 | 5 | 2011-12-17
1 | 8 | 2011-09-03
2 | 8 | 2011-11-12
1 | 9 | 2011-10-08
2 | 9 | 2011-10-10
3 | 9 | 2011-11-19
```

The middle column represents the fk_id. As you can see, the sorting and row count is within the fk_id "grouping."

**UPDATE**
I have a query that seems to be working, but would like some input as to whether it can be improved:

```
SELECT IF(@last = c.fk_id, @row:=@row +1, @row:=1) AS ordinality, @last:=c.fk_id, c.fk_id, rcv_date
FROM (SELECT @row:=0) r, (SELECT @last:=0) l, mytable c
ORDER BY c.fk_id, rcv_date
```

So what this does is order by fk_id and then rcv_date -- which essentially handles my grouping. Then I use a second variable to compare the fk_id in the previous record with the current record: if it's the same, we increment the row; if different, we reset to 1.

My tests with real data appear to be working. I suspect it's a pretty inefficient query though -- so if anyone has ideas for improving it, or see possible flaws, I would love to hear.

Comment: @Icdservices you shouldn't order by that in the same query. It will spoil your hard earned ordinality. First order it in an inner query and then do the ranking as in my solution

Answer (score 3):

This should be pretty straightforward.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN @fk <> fk_id THEN @row:=1 ELSE @row:=@row + 1 END) AS ordinality, 
       @fk:=fk_id, rcv_date
FROM   (SELECT @row:=0) AS r, 
       (SELECT @fk:=0) AS f, 
       (SELECT fk_id, rcv_date FROM files ORDER BY fk_id, rcv_date) AS t
```

I ordered by `fk_id` first to ensure all your foreign keys come together (what if they are not really in the table?), then I did your preferred ordering, ie by `rcv_date`. The query checks for a change in fk_id and if there is one, then row number variable is set to 1, or else the variable is incremented. Its handled in case statement. Notice that `@fk:=fk_id` is done after the case checking else it will affect the row number.

**Edit:** Just noticed your own solution which happened to be the same as I ended up with. Kudos! :)