# SQL index relative to another field

Tags: sql

I have, as part of a query, a bunch of distinct pairs of values:

```
a       d
a       e
a       f
b       g
b       h
c       i
```

I'd like to be able to calculate an counter relative to the first field:

```
a       d       1
a       e       2
a       f       3
b       g       1
b       h       2
c       i       1
```

I can't use the position in the temporary table - apart from anything else it goes too high, whereas the value I need can't go over 2 digits (and there isn't going to be more than 50 entries with the same first field. Are there any methods or techniques to help?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I would suggest rewording your question to avoid confusion, since _index_ has a quite distinct meaning when talking about databases. Let's name it _position_ or _counter_?

Comment: I think you mean _row number within group_.

Comment: If you're using MySQL, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216427/row-number-for-query-results-grouped-by-a-column

Comment: Search for `row_number over partition by` along with the name of your database (e.g. Oracle, MSSQL, MySQL, etc) and you'll likely find a bunch of answers.

Comment: @JohnLBevan: MySQL still does not support window functions.

Comment: Barmar - SQL on the IBM iSeries, I'm afraid - no custom code likely to work, which is why I was looking for an algorithmic solution.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name agreed; afarrell didn't state which db he was using; so it may or may not be mysql.  However searching this site for those keywords you'll probably find "How to I do a `row_number() over (partition by ...)` in mysql" which will answer the question.

Comment: @afarrell: DB2 (also on iSeries) supports window functions if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.c1 , t1.c2 , count(t2.c1) cnt
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1 and t1.c2 >= t2.c2
group by t1.c1, t1.c2
order by t1.c1, cnt
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6ca67/2)

**Explanation**

This query assumes that the pair `(c1,c2)` is unique.

To rank each row `(c1,c2)` the query counts the number of rows within the group `c1` where `c2` is less than or equal to `c2`. For example, for `(a,e)`, there are 2 rows within the group `a` that are less than or equal to `e` (namely `d` and `e`).

Comment: Can you explain how this code answers the question?

Comment: Any explanation would be good, answers that just contain code blocks aren't always as self explanatory as it may seem to the person who wrote it.

Comment: Just a heads up, it landed in the "low quality review" that's where I saw it and added the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select a,
       b,
       row_number() over (partition by a order by b) as idx
from the_table;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4cf96/1

`row_number()` is a window function which will generate a unique number based on the "grouping" and ordering defined with the `partition by` clause. The Postgres manual has a nice introduction to window functions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

This is going to be much faster than a self join